# Java Spring: How to see how many entities/rows are affected by a repository.delete method?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, repository, spring-data

Within my application (that uses `Spring Data` and extending the `CrudRepository`), I am deleting Entities using:

```
repository.delete(Dog);
```

This triggers a `Cascade-delete` on other tables/entities. (note: `Hibernate` is my JPA implementation)

Is there a way to see how many rows/entities this has deleted from the Database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't, not at least at JPA level. If you take a look to the `EntityManager` class (which means going one step deeper than Spring Data), you'll see its [`remove`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#remove-java.lang.Object-) method returns nothing. The [`delete`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/repository/CrudRepository.html#delete-java.lang.Iterable-) metod of the Spring Data Crud repository does it too.

In short words, that's something you'll have to manage in your transactional methods, even more if you want to take into account the related entities which could be implied in a cascade operation.

Comment: Thanks, do you know how I could identify the entities that were deleted via the cascade operation?

Comment: The cascade mode might be quite handy in some situations but doesn't really give any feedback of what's going under the hoods. If you really are interested in what's being removed, you should think about not doing the cascade way, but calling delete for each collection element .