# How to check for success/failure in Java Spring database queries?

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, sql-delete

I have some code to delete a recipe from my mongoDB database:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/recipe/{id}", method = RequestMethod.DELETE)
public String deleteSingleRecipe(@PathVariable("id") String recipeId) {
    try {
        repository.deleteById(recipeId);
        return "Deleted RECIPE success";
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        return ex.toString();
    }
}
```

This is able to successfully delete a recipe based on ID. However, I'm unsure how to catch cases such as if the recipe doesn't even exist, or if the deletion is failed.

With JavaScript/Node this was really easy because I could pass a callback function with depending on if result/error were null I could determine the success of the query and proceed. I'm pretty lost how to do this in Java/Spring.

When I tried to delete a recipe a 2nd time I still got "Deleted RECIPE success".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a check before using [existsById](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/repository/CrudRepository.html#existsById-ID-)

```
boolean isFound = repository.existsById(recipeId);
```

> Returns whether an entity with the given id exists.

Comment: I suppose this is acceptable, but also requires an additional read to the database. Also, I was looking for more of a "generalized" solution instead of just to solve my 1 problem. For example, what if I add a new item to the DB? Is the only way to check if it was successfully really to do a check afterwards to see if it exists in the database? (Also at this point how would I get the ID to check for that object in the database?) The lack of return values or data is frustrating.

Comment: @Birdman if you will use `jdbcTemplate` it will return number of rows updated, see https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html#update-org.springframework.jdbc.core.PreparedStatementCreator- see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36021525/java-spring-how-to-see-how-many-entities-rows-are-affected-by-a-repository-dele

Comment: Well in this case it's not jdbcTemplate but MongoTemplate wil remove methods that return a DeleteResult

Comment: As @JEY suggested there's also MongoTemplate remove methods as https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/MongoTemplate.html#doRemove-java.lang.String-org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Query-java.lang.Class-boolean-

Comment: This was helpful to address my comment: Since the MongoRepsitory implements CredRepository there was some info here about save(): https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-crud-repository-save

"The save() method returns the saved entity, including the updated id field."

Answer (score 1):

If you check the JPARepository Interface you will get

```
/**
     * Deletes the entity with the given id.
     * 
     * @param id must not be {@literal null}.
     * @throws IllegalArgumentException in case the given {@code id} is {@literal null}
     */
    void deleteById(ID id);

/**
     * Deletes a given entity.
     * 
     * @param entity
     * @throws IllegalArgumentException in case the given entity is {@literal null}.
     */
    void delete(T entity);
```

so as per your requirement it will not throw any exception if given id is not exist in DB.

for that you can use `boolean isFound = repository.existsById(recipeId);` and if `isFound` is true you can delete it. and if `isFound` is false then you can throw exception.

second way is you can check

```
  public class SimpleJpaRepository<T, ID> implements JpaRepository<T, ID>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<T>
```

this class contains `deleteById` method. and this method will throw exception if `id` is not exist in DB.

```
/*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * @see org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository#delete(java.io.Serializable)
     */
    @Transactional
    public void deleteById(ID id) {

        Assert.notNull(id, ID_MUST_NOT_BE_NULL);

        delete(findById(id).orElseThrow(() -> new EmptyResultDataAccessException(
                String.format("No %s entity with id %s exists!", entityInformation.getJavaType(), id), 1)));
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Starting from Spring Data JPA (>=1.7.x), we can use the derived `delete` or `remove` query. It returns the number of entities deleted or what all entities are deleted.

Using it you can update your code as:

```
public interface RecipetRepository extends CrudRepository<Reciepe, Long> {
    long deleteById(String id);
}
```

and we can throw an exception if the entity doesn't exist.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/recipe/{id}", method = RequestMethod.DELETE)
public String deleteSingleRecipe(@PathVariable("id") String recipeId) {
    long numberOfRecipiesDeleted;
    try {
        numberOfRecipiesDeleted = repository.deleteById(recipeId);
    } catch (DataAccessException ex) {
        return ex.toString();
    }
    if(numberOfRecipiesDeleted == 0){
      throw new ReciepeNotFoundException();
    }
    return "Deleted RECIPE success";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try add a new method to the repository interface like this

```
@Modifying
@Query("DELETE FROM MY_TABLE WHERE ID = ?1")
default boolean deleteById(IdPrimitiveType id){
  return true;
 }
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

It has been reported to Spring as a bug (which is still open) : https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAMONGO-1997?jql=text%20~%20%22deleteById%22

Checking if it exists before or after was not a solution for us as it is sensitive to race condition. The best and more efficient workaround we found was what @SandOfTime suggested : in your MongoRepository interface, add :

```
@DeleteQuery("{_id:?0}")
Long deleteByIdReturningDeletedCount(String id);
```

Answer (score 0):

I also had a similar kind of requirement but my case is slightly different. First I'll tell my requirement I need to add a user if the username is not exist. So in the Repository there is a built in method to find the username.

```
Usermodel findByUsername(String username);
```

So in the Controller layer I've implemented the following.

```
public String signUp(@RequestBody Usermodel user) {
        if(userRepository.findByUsername(user.getUsername())==null) {
            userRepository.save(user);
            return "Success";
        }
        else{
            return "Username Already Exsist";
        }
    }
```

I think for your case also this can be applied. Need to check the recipeId and then you can perform a deletion.